# Display Field Collection items inplace of field_links? Drupal 8.1.3

Tags: drupal, drupal-field-collection

I am Newbie to Drupal. I want to create a plant taxonomy website to my college. Here I add a image field with description field inside field collection. It displays inside a new page. But I want to display field collection data in the same page in place of the link(field_parts_of_plant 0).

Here the image for your reference
[image: in-place of field_parts_of_plant 0]

Help me to do this!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works fine after adding "reference table formatter" module. Drupal 8 is awesome[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k4YS2.png)